# What do you call a threaded sink strainer that doesn't seal when screwed-in?

Tags: plumbing, kitchens, sink, kitchen-sink, clog

Is there a keyword I can use to identify a type of sink strainer that screws into place such that it still allows water to flow when it's tightened (by hand)?

I'm looking for a sink strainer for my kitchen sink that [a] won't float out of place and [b] won't stop the water from draining out of the sink.

| [image: photo of a lightweight aftermarket sink strainer] | [image: photo of a heavy sink strainer with a rubber gasket] |
| --- | --- |
| Cheap strainers easily get dislodged | Expensive strainers have gaskets that accidentally stop the water flow |

Currently my kitchen sink has a simple metal strainer that's supposed to prevent food scraps from going down the drain. If it would just stay in-place, it might work. But often when doing dishes, it gets knocked out of place by the water -- often floating-up to the side of the sink when doing dishes and the food scraps just go right down the drain. Very frustrating.

What I'd like to do is replace this aftermarket drain strainer with something purpose-built in the sink. Ideally the strainer would be able to quickly screw into place (by hand with the thumb) so that it couldn't accidentally get dislodged.

I've seen some sink strainers in the past that could be screwed into place, but they were designed with a rubber stopper to stop-up the drain (eg to fill the basin for soaking). That's not what I want. I want it to screw into place *and* allow the water to flow out of the basin (just not the large food particles).

Is there a name for a type of sink strainer that can securely screw into place without stopping the flow of water?

Comment: Why would it be floating up? They are generally considerably heavier than water.

Comment: I mean worst case, get some copper wire and a lead weight, wire the weight 3/4" below the bottom of the cheap strainer.

Comment: The standard, run-of-the-mill sink stopper has no threads, sits securely in the drain opening but does not stop the water flow until the central stem is turned to a special orientation which lets the stopper drop down. It's virtually impossible to accidentally stop the water flow with those. They work fine, are very inexpensive, and available everywhere.

Answer (score 3):

You can get strainers that do not have the stopper gasket. Sometimes they're just a dome of hardware cloth with an edge crimped to it. Check what's on offer at your local hardware store or home center, or do some catalog searching; in my experience these are fairly common.

They aren't threaded. They don't need threads. I don't think I've ever seen a sink stopper that *was* threaded ... Or a sink that had threads to engage one if you did find it.